# Split line with perl

Tags: perl, line-processing

```
   title: Football team: Real Madrid stadium: Santiago Bernabeu players: Zinédine Zidane, Ronaldo, Luís Figo, Roberto Carlos, Raúl personnel: José Mourinho (head coach) Aitor Karanka (assistant coach (es))
```

How to split this with perl in:

```
   title: Football
   team: Real Madrid
   stadium: Santiago Bernabeu
   players: Zinédine Zidane Ronaldo Luís Figo Roberto Carlos Raúl
   personnel: José Mourinho (head coach) Aitor Karanka (assistant coach (es))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a lookahead assertion:

```
say for split /(?=\w+:)/, $real_madrid_string;
```

**Output**

```
title: Football
team: Real Madrid
stadium: Santiago Bernabeu
players: Zinédine Zidane Ronaldo Luís Figo Roberto Carlos Raúl
personnel: José Mourinho (head coach) Aitor Karanka (assistant coach (es))
```

Comment: If translate "players" in another language: "players" = "jucător", zero-width lookahead found character "ă" instead of colon ":" (a word character that is interpreted a non word charachter) and split here. Thanks.

Comment: Then your Perl version is not new enough to directly support this.  You can try to split on `\P{Letter}` instead, but I guess you will also need to wiggle with Perl options to get it into an UTF8 kind of mood, maybe with Perl `-CSD`.  Maybe one or the other will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it. line.txt contains "title: Football team: Real Madrid stadium: Santiago Bernabeu players: Zinédine Zidane, Ronaldo, Luís Figo, Roberto Carlos, Raúl personnel: José Mourinho (head coach) Aitor Karanka (assistant coach (es))"

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fn="./line.txt";

open(IN,$fn);
my @lines=<IN>;

my %hash;
my $hashKey;

foreach my $line (@lines){
        $line=~s/\n//g;
        my @split1=split(" +",$line);
        foreach my $split (@split1){
                if($split=~m/:$/){
                        $hashKey=$split;
                }else{
                        if(defined($hash{$hashKey})){
                                $hash{$hashKey}=$hash{$hashKey}.$split." ";
                        }else{
                                $hash{$hashKey}=$split." ";
                        }
                }
        }
}

close(IN);


foreach my $key (keys %hash){
        print $key.":".$hash{$key}."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what many are saying in their answers, you do not need lookahead (other than the Regex's own), you would only need to *capture* part of the delimiter, like so:

```
my @hash_fields = grep { length; } split /\s*(\w+):\s*/;
```

My full solution below:

```
my %handlers
    = ( players   => sub { return [ grep { length; } split /\s*,\s*/, shift ]; }
      , personnel => sub { 
            my $value = shift;
            my %personnel;
            # Using recursive regex for nested parens
            while ( $value =~ m/([^(]*)([(](?:[^()]+|(?2))*[)])/g ) {
                my ( $name, $role ) = ( $1, $2 );
                $role =~ s/^\s*[(]\s*//;
                $role =~ s/\s*[)]\s*$//;
                $name =~ s/^\s+//;
                $name =~ s/\s+$//;
                $personnel{ $role } = $name;
            }
            return \%personnel;
        }
      );
my %hash = grep { length; } split /(?:^|\s+)(\w+):\s+/, <DATA>;
foreach my $field ( keys %handlers ) { 
    $hash{ $field } = $handlers{ $field }->( $hash{ $field } );
}
```

Dump looks like this:

```
%hash: {
     personnel => {
                    'assistant coach (es)' => 'Aitor Karanka',
                    'head coach' => 'José Mourinho'
                  },
     players => [
                  'Zinédine Zidane',
                  'Ronaldo',
                  'Luís Figo',
                  'Roberto Carlos',
                  'Raúl'
                ],
     stadium => 'Santiago Bernabeu',
     team => 'Real Madrid',
     title => 'Football'
   }
```

Comment: $value =~ m/([^(]*)([(](?:[^()]+|(?2))*[)])/g  Undefined (?...) sequence.

Comment: @user935420, don't know what problem you're having with it. In my strawberry perl 5.12 and ActivePerl 5.14, it works without a hitch.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the `split` command using a zero-width lookahead:

```
$string = "title: Football team: Real Madrid stadium: Santiago Bernabeu players: Zinédine Zidane, Ronaldo, Luís Figo, Roberto Carlos, Raúl personnel: José Mourinho (head coach) Aitor Karanka (assistant coach (es))";

@split_string = split /(?=\b\w+:)/, $string;
```

Comment: sorry... I escaped the `)` out of habit from using Vim.

Comment: If translate "players" in another language: "players" = "jucător", zero-width lookahead found character "ă" and split here. Thanks.

Comment: @user: you have to make sure that your locale settings are correct.  `\w` is explicitly designed to be used in a locale-agnostic way, and the locale differences should be handled under the hood.

Comment: @user: look here for how to handle locales:http://perldoc.perl.org/perllocale.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "title: Football team: Real Madrid stadium: Santiago Bernabeu players: Zinédine Zidane, Ronaldo, Luís Figo, Roberto Carlos, Raúl personnel: José Mourinho (head coach) Aitor Karanka (assistant coach (es))";
@words = split(' ', $string);

@lines = undef;
@line = shift(@words);
foreach $word (@words)
{
    if ($word =~ /:/)
    {
        push(@lines, join(' ', @line));
        @line = undef;
    }
    else
    {
        push(@line, $word);
    }
}

print join("\n", @lines);
```

Comment: This won't work, because Perl doesn't have the concept of an array of arrays.  the first `push` will simply concatenate the contents of `@line` onto the end of `@lines`.  In order for this to work, `@lines` has to be an array of *references* to arrays, generated by `@line`.

Comment: @lines is an array of strings, I only ever push strings into it

Comment: It is often a good idea to run your code before you post it. This won't run at all. I can see a missing semi-colon for starters. `push` takes an array as it's first argument, and you probably meant to concatenate there. But even then it begs the question, why go round the long way?

Comment: ahh, I always get confused about the order of the arguments to push. As for why, I'm new to perl and didn't think about lookahead

Comment: @Zaid: I wouldn't fault Bwmat for not thinking of the lookahead.  After all, there's more than one way to to it.

Comment: Me neither. @Bwmat I too was in your shoes at one time. Just remember that it is very easy to overlook the simple-yet-powerful features provided by Perl in lieu of C/Java-style coding conventions.