# Split with line with perl

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split line with perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386215/split-line-with-perl)

I have a line:

```
regizor: Betty Thomas Distribuţia: Sandra Bullock (Gwen Cummings) Viggo Mortensen (Eddie Boone) Dominic West (Jasper) rendező: David Mamet, Robert Elswit szereplő(k): Chiwetel Ejiofor (Mike Terry) Alice Braga (Sondra Terry) Emily Mortimer (Laura Black)
```

I want to split with perl in:

```
regizor: Betty Thomas
Distribuţia: Sandra Bullock (Gwen Cummings) Viggo Mortensen (Eddie Boone) Dominic West (Jasper)
rendező: David Mamet Robert Elswit
szereplő(k): Chiwetel Ejiofor (Mike Terry) Alice Braga (Sondra Terry) Emily Mortimer (Laura Black)
```

Comment: Will it always be split on the keywords `regizor`, `Distributia`, `rendezo` and `szereplo(k)` ?

Comment: No, there may be other credits.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395905/perl-html-data-and-characters-encoded-in-utf-8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
my @splitBits = split /(?=\S+: )/, $str;
```

This will split the string before every occurrence of a "word" (a sequence of non-space characters) followed by a colon and a space (and without producing an empty field at the beginning).

Answer (score 5):

You could use the following regex:

```
$line =~ s/(\S+:)/\n$1/sg;
```

This says "Find any non-space character (\S), at least once (+), which has a colon after it, and stick a new line in front of it."

You'll get a leading newline which you can chop off easily.

When I ran it on your line, I got

```
regizor: Betty Thomas 
Distribuţia: Sandra Bullock (Gwen Cummings) Viggo Mortensen (Eddie Boone) Dominic West (Jasper) 
rendező: David Mamet, Robert Elswit 
szereplő(k): Chiwetel Ejiofor (Mike Terry) Alice Braga (Sondra Terry) Emily Mortimer (Laura Black)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -p -e 's/ ([^ ]*?:)/\n$1/g' <file.txt
```

Gives:

```
regizor: Betty Thomas
Distribu.ia: Sandra Bullock (Gwen Cummings) Viggo Mortensen (Eddie Boone) Dominic West (Jasper)
rendez.: David Mamet, Robert Elswit
szerepl.(k): Chiwetel Ejiofor (Mike Terry) Alice Braga (Sondra Terry) Emily Mortimer (Laura Black)
```

Comment: What happened to your encoding?